# If my Mac App works, do I have to fix sandboxing "violations"?

Tags: macos, sandbox

I am preparing my Mac app for sandboxing. Although my app runs properly (doing everything it should), I still see a few sandboxing violations when using Console. For example, when tying to use OpenFile:WithApplication: to open up a pdf file (located in my bundle) using Adobe Reader, it actually works properly, but I do see the following...

```
sandboxd:  deny file-write-data /Applications/Adobe Reader.app
sandboxd:  deny file-write-data /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyPDFfile.pdf
```

I'm not really attempting to write anything, just trying to open the pdf up for reading using this code...

```
NSString *MyPDFFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyPDFfile.pdf"];  

NSString* adobeReaderPath = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:@"com.adobe.Reader"];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:MyPDFFilePath withApplication:[adobeReaderPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/MacOS/AdobeReader"]];
```

Also, I have used...

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:MyPDFFilePath withApplication:@"Adobe Reader"];
```

Anyway, my question is this: If opening up the pdf file actually works, should I be concerned about these "violations"? Or should I just ignore them, since the program functions correctly?

If the "violations" do need to be addressed, how should I go about it?
Thanks for any assistance on this.

Comment: The violations are on Adobe Reader's part. Besides, you should avoid hardcoding the application name: lots of people don't have Adobe Reader installed on their Macs as Preview supports reading PDF files.

Comment: Actually, it's my app that's being flagged for the violation, and not Adobe Reader. Also, Preview does not display my pdf correctly (it's in another language). Only Reader displays it properly.